# PostgreSQL: Replace values greater than a certain limit in array elements

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, replace, conditional-statements

I have 3 rows of array (type, text) in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database like follows:

```
ID     array
1      "112,292,19.3"
2      "203,383,22.1"
3      "136,226,18.9,286,346,27.1,346,406,6.5"
```

There are some array elements which are greater than 360. I want to replace them on a condition that `if any array element > 360` then `element - 360` so that the replaced array be like:

```
ID     array
1      "112,292,19.3"
2      "203,23,22.1"
3      "136,226,18.9,286,346,27.1,346,46,6.5"
```

How can I replace values greater than 360?

Comment: and if they are gt then 720?..

Comment: 360 is the certain limit for the elements. That's why I want to scan all the elements if they are greater than 360.

Comment: try `mod` as in my answer example. of course it will give replace 721 with 1, not 361, but I have an impression it's what you finaly will want?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [modulo operator `%`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html) in Postgres:

```
with my_table(id, arr) as (
values
    (1, array[112,292,19.3]),
    (2, array[203,383,22.1]),
    (3, array[136,226,18.9,286,346,27.1,346,406,6.5])
)

select id, array_agg(unnest % 360 order by ordinality)
from my_table,
unnest(arr) with ordinality
group by 1;

 id |               array_agg                
----+----------------------------------------
  1 | {112,292,19.3}
  2 | {203,23,22.1}
  3 | {136,226,18.9,286,346,27.1,346,46,6.5}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Probably more compact (I believe that the order is stored): `select id, array(select unnest(arr) % 360) from my_table;`

Comment: This assumption is a bit risky. When in future you add something (e.g. a where condition) you'll be surprised why the order is changed.

Comment: Yes. But from other hand we do not need the additional memory for join result and additional scan for grouping. Risk vs efficiency :)

Answer (score 1):

try https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-math.html
`mod`

> remainder of y/x

eg:

```
x=# with a as (select * from unnest(array[136,226,18.9,286,346,27.1,346,46,6.5]) with ordinality a(i,o))
select array_agg(mod(i,360) order by o) from a;
               array_agg
----------------------------------------
 {136,226,18.9,286,346,27.1,346,46,6.5}
(1 row)
```